# TypeErrors when I try to plot dict

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib

I have a dict that I want to plot:

```
my_dict={'a': 0.015015015015015015,
 'b': 2.0,
 'c': 0.0,
 'd-e': 0.14,
 'f': 0.0
 nan: 0.06
}
```

This code is giving an error

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

lists = sorted(my_dict.items()) # sorted by key, return a list of tuples

x, y = zip(*lists) # unpack a list of pairs into two tuples

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

> -> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

while this other

```
plt.bar(list(my_dict.keys()), list(my_dict.values()))
```

returns the error

> -> TypeError: 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float

How can I plot it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that `plot` expects numbers to plot. So you can just do

```
x, y = zip(*lists) # unpack a list of pairs into two tuples

x_num = np.arange(len(x)) # Numbers to plot

plt.plot(x_num, y)
plt.xticks(x_num, labels=x) # Replace x_num with your labels in x
plt.show()
```

And get

[image: Plot]

If there is a `np.nan` as a key in your dictionary, you can always replace it with another key that suits you best:

```
my_dict['not nan'] = my_dict.pop(np.nan) # Replace

# Plot
lists = sorted(my_dict.items()) # sorted by key, return a list of tuples
x, y = zip(*lists) # unpack a list of pairs into two tuples

plt.bar(list(my_dict.keys()), list(my_dict.values()))
```

And get

[image: bar plot]

Comment: Thanks Camilo. Where should I replace my dict in the first code? If I uses lists as I defined in my question I get the same error. I think the error is caused by nan

Comment: @LdM I hadn't noticed the `nan` in `my_dict`. I edited my answer to include that case